# No consigo ejecutar el jar de mi aplicación

Tags: java, jar

Hola a todos y gracias de antemano. Después de terminar mi aplicación he creado el jar, lo ha creado en la carpeta dist del proyecto de netbeans. Pero a la hora de ejecutarlo me devuelve un error de que no se encuentra la clase principal.

[image: Error]

He comprobado en las propiedades del proyecto que en el menú build -> packing esté activada la casilla compress jar file. Tambien he comprobado despues de crear el jar, en descomprimirlo con winrar y en el mainfest.mf que estaría en la carpeta META-INF esté la línea agregada de  `Main-Class: clinica.Clinica`

he comprobado muchas cosas y no se que hacer más. Tengo que decir que si ejecuto la aplicación desde CMD navegando hasta la ubicación del archivo y posteriormente ejecutando `java -jar "Clinica.jar"` se ejecuta la aplicación perfectamente, pero debería de poder ejecutarse con doble click.

También tengo que comentar, que he probado con otros proyectos de netbeans y todos me aparece el mismo error, no se si es que está mal configurado o no se

gracias de antemano

Comment: Me pasaba lo mismo. Para ejecutar un jar debes tener instalado el entorno de ejecución de java (java se runtime) y configurarlo en la opción `abrir con`

Comment: Efectivamente era eso compañero. muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes seleccionar el archivo de ejecución principal.
Esto se hace seleccionando el proyecto, click derecho, selecciona Propiedades, seleccionas la categoria Run y alli puedes cambiar el Main Class.
En cuanto a darle doble click al archivo de ejecución, para que este sea ejecutado, puedes darle click derecho al jar y seleccionar ejecutar con otra aplicacion y alli buscas la carpeta de java runtime en tu disco local hasta encontrar el archivo java que permite ejecutar tu aplicación para que quede predeterminada para uso posterior para cualquier otra app.

[image: Procedimiento Visual]

Comment: Era eso, no tenia instalado el runtime y por eso no me ejecutaba. Muchas gracias a ambos